Late 80s or early 90s summer camp movie
SO, I've been desperately searching for the title of this movie. It's a summer camp movie - teens and their antics when away from home... I know, not super helpful. 
Now, here's a clue that I hope is significant. One of the main characters is a red haired guy. This young fellow acted on a Nickelodean show at one time, I think. Not of the Pete and Pete fame, though. Anyway, I know for sure that as an adult he went on to host some kid themed game show. I want to say it was a Nick game show, but I could be wrong on that point. 
I remember the game show thing, because when I saw it I was all like, "Hey, it's the redhead guy from that camp movie all grown up!"
Does this ring a bell for anyone? Anyone? Please! :)

Usually, I remember specific scenes from movies pretty easily. It's weird, because I remember nothing from this movie except the red haired boy! Lol, it's maddening.

Is it The Wilder Summer from 1983?  It had red-haired JD Roth who hosted various shows in the 90s and was supposedly on heavy rotation on HBO.  
Here it is on YouTube (the condensed 32 min version anyway--originally was 54 mins).

This is it!!! Omg, you're seriously the most awesome person on earth!!
